# Do we not need [knot-theory]?

Tags: discussion, tags

A recent challenge ([A Rather Knotty Conundrum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/102466/34718)) added the [knot-theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knot-theory) tag. No previous knot theory challenges use this tag yet. Before I consider using the tag, I want to see if the tag is really necessary. This tag might make sense on Math.SE, but it seems pretty specific for our use on PPCG, and there are only three or four existing challenges that could deserve the tag:

1. ["KNOT" or "NOT"?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/30292/knot-or-not)
2. [A Rather Knotty Conundrum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102466/a-rather-knotty-conundrum)
3. [Gasket Weaving - draw a Sierpiński knot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79650/gasket-weaving-draw-a-sierpi%c5%84ski-knot)
4. [ASCII Art of the Day #1 - Double Knot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50484/ascii-art-of-the-day-1-double-knot) (probably not)

Should we remove this tag, or keep it (and tag the existing challenges)?

Comment: New title: `I have a theory: we do 'knot' need this tag`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Keep it

It's not doing any harm. The difficulty of the tagged challenges, or the number of answers they receive is irrelevant for whether the tag is useful. If someone *does* answer one of those tough challenges, there's a good chance they're interested in the general topic and would like to find more of knot theory challenges. The tag helps them do exactly that, regardless of whether there's only 4 or 40 applicable challenges.

Comment: As a side note I'm not entirely convinced that this entire question isn't just a setup for a really bad pun...

Comment: It's not a setup. I found all the questions that were related simply by searching for the word "knot", and so I think we don't need the tag.

Comment: In fact, I was primarily asking because I was going to ask a knot-theory question, and I wanted to know how to tag it. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/103743/34718

Answer (score -3):

## It's not necessary. Remove it.

There are only a few related questions, and the existing questions receive few answers due to the complexity of the field and the programming required (each of the likely candidates has only a single answer.)

Because of this, the tag is not necessary, and [geometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) can be used instead.

Comment: Knot theory is topology, not geometry.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Well, the questions using knot theory were tagged geometry.